Is it a good practice to use AB testing to choose threshold of ML models?
Assuming there is a ML model learning the likelihood of an item being clicked by users. The output is typically a number between [0,1] indicating the probability of the item. Then you need to decide a threshold to assign class labels or other decisions. There are always business concerns added to the decision process to balance the precision and recall. My question: is it a good practice to use AB testing to decide the threshold value?
This is more of a general discussion on AB testing practices. The question is submitted to ChatGPT, Claude and Gemini. All of them responded with YES. Google search also didn't come up with any discussions on this topic. Here's my list of pros and cons:
Pros:

Directly shown the effect in  business metrics.
Easier to communicate and make decisions in teams since results are real online results.

Cons:

It takes much longer to iterate. AB tests typically take weeks.
Costly, bad experience hurt user experience, traffic is occupied, can't do other tests
p-hacking, you can test 100 thresholds, and even your model doesn't do anything good, there will be 5 winning thresholds if we are setting alpha at 0.05.

Any thoughts on this problem?
